# Fill Matrix in a special order C++

Tags: c++

I want to fill a 8 x 8 matrix with values in a special order (see example below), but I don´t know how to do that. Each numer stands for the ordering number: For example: #3 in the matrix is the third value of a e.g. a measurment I want to add.
The Order should be:

```
1   2   5   6    17  18  21  22
3   4   7   8    19  20  23  24
9   10  13  14   25  26  29  30
11  12  15  16   27  28  31  32

33  34  37  38   49  50  53  54
35  36  39  40   51  52  55  56
41  42  45  46   57  58  61  62  
43  44  47  48   59  60  63  64
```

Does anybody knows an algorithmus to do that? 
I have tried this, but that´s not a good way to to it, and it´s not working for the whole matrix

```
int b= 0, ii = 0, a = 0, iii = 0


i are different measurement values

and now a for loop  


                    if (ii == 1)
                    {
                        b++;

                    }
                    if (ii == 2)
                    {
                        a++, b--;

                    }
                    if (ii == 3)
                    {
                        b ++;

                    }
                    tempMatrix[a][b] = i;
                    cout << "TempMatrix " << tempMatrix[a][b] << "   a " << a << "  b " << b << endl;
                    if (ii == 3)
                    {
                        ii = -1;

                        a --;
                        b ++;

                    }
                    if (iii == 7)
                    {
                        a = a + 2;
                        b = 0;
                        iii = -1;
                    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? stack overflow isn't a code writing service

Comment: If you already know the size of the matrix and what numbers to put in, it should be trivial to add the numbers in. If you want to *generate* an nxn matrix with this pattern, that's a different issue.

Comment: I don´t want a full code. Just an idea, how to to that.

Comment: If it's a fixed size you don't need a special algorithm, if you can't think of a concise way to do it you could just literally spell out your assignments `mat(1,1) = first_measurement; mat(1,2) = second_measurement; mat(2,1) = third_measurement; // so on`

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Are the values of a and b correct? We need an [mcve], input, expected output and actual output to help further

Comment: Identify the part of the pattern that repeats, then determine how many times to repeat it. In this case, it looks like the repeating pattern is the act of writing four elements in a 2x2 square. It's the second part that's tricky - spotting edge cases (e.g. the destination height or width are odd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use recursion:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void f(int a[8][8], int current, int x, int y, int size) {
    if (size == 1) {
        a[x][y] = current;
        return;
    } else {
        size /= 2;
        int add_for_each_square = size * size;
        f(a, current, x, y, size);
        f(a, current + add_for_each_square, x, y + size, size);
        f(a, current + 2 * add_for_each_square, x + size, y, size);
        f(a, current + 3 * add_for_each_square, x + size, y + size, size);
    }
}

int main() {
   int a[8][8];
   f(a, 1, 0, 0, 8);
   for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
       for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j) {
           cout << a[i][j] << " ";
       }
       cout << endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: the OP is trying to set the value of the array in a certain order not to the specified values. e.g. `[1][0]` should be set to the 3rd value not to 3.

Comment: @AlanBirtles that can easily be fixed by `a[x][y] = val[current]` or by doing something like `b[x][y] = val[a[x][y]]`. Also you can write a function that takes `x, y` and returns the ordering number using the same technique. And OP commented his question: "Just an idea, how to do that"

Answer (score 1):

If the matrix will always be a fixed size, then you can generate two lookup tables for row and column indexes into the matrix. Then, just pass your index through these tables to get the desired positions in the matrix.

```
const auto MATRIX_SIZE = 8;
const std::array<int, MATRIX_SIZE*MATRIX_SIZE> row_lookup = {{...}}; //put pre-computed values here. 
const std::array<int, MATRIX_SIZE*MATRIX_SIZE> col_lookup = {{...}};

for(size_t i = 0; i < MATRIX_SIZE * MATRIX_SIZE; i++)
{
    auto val = get_coefficient(i);
    auto row = row_lookup[i];
    auto col = col_lookup[i];

    mat[col][row] = val;
}
```